# Postgres Function - SQLs in Loop really a prepared Statement?

Tags: performance, function, postgresql, loops, plpgsql

Right now I am doing for my company a migration from Firebird 2.5 to Postgres 9.4 and I also converted Stored Procedures from Firebird into Functions to Postgres...

Now I figured out that the performance is quite slow, but only if there are loops in which I execute more SQLs whith changing parameters.

So for example it looks like this (I simplified it to the necessary things)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST
(TEST_ID BigInt) returns TABLE(NAME VARCHAR)
AS $$
declare _tmp bigint;
begin
for _tmp in select id from test 
loop
-- Shouldn't the following SQL work as a Prepared Statement?
for name in select label
from test2
where id = _tmp
loop
return next;
end loop;

end loop;

end; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So if I compare the the time it takes to execute just the select inside the loop with Postgres and Firebird then Postgres is usually a bit faster than Firebird. But if the loop runs like 100 or 1000 or 10000 times than the time of the Firebird Stored Procedure is much faster. When I compare the times in Postgres it seemes like if the loop runs 10 times it takes 10 times longer then 1 row and if it runs 1000 times it takes 1000 times longer.... That should not be if it its reallly a Prepared Statement, right?

I checked also other issues like setting the memory settings high, leaving the statement "return next" out because I read that can cause a performance problem also.... 
It has also nothing to do with the "returns table" expression. If I leave that out it takes also the same time..
Nothing worked so far...

Of course this simple example could be solved also with one SQL, but the functions I migrated are much more complicated and I don't want to change the whole functions into something new (if possible)...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Running a statement inside a loop is very often a sign of a bad approach. It is almost always better to create a single statement that processes everything in a set oriented manner. You said you don't want to do that, it's most probably the best way to tune this. Given the information you have shown us it is impossible to answer your question

Comment: It's a example you would never want to see in production, it's slow by design. Another part of the performance issue might be a missing index in the test2 table. Hard to tell without the table definition and data.

Comment: the thing is i migrated over 30 procedures that have queries inside of loops and are often 400 to 800 lines of code. Even if that is a bad approach I don't have the time to write them all new. My question is just why is Firebird able to handle those SQLs inside of loops really as Prepared Statements and it makes there hardly a difference if the loop runs 10 or 10000 times and why in Postgres not? And have I just missed a point and only need to add a keyword/setting at some point to make it fast like in Firebird...

Comment: Missing indixes can not be the problem because if I run those SQLs inside the loop alone as SQL Statements they are even faster than in Firebird

Comment: It could also be a memory issue after X loops.

Comment: also considered that... but i increased all the memory settings in the postgresql.conf and it made no difference.

Comment: strange thing the performance is really increasing linear to the number of loops. So 1000 loops means the function takes 1000 times as long. So it is really constant and doesnt seem like that at one point it is out of memory and takes then forever... So it really looks to me it is not a prepared statement inside that loop

Comment: @Steffen - it is prepared statement - and linear behave is expected - this query is relative simple, so cost for preparation is low (c1), you can see a cost for execution (c2) .. t = c1(~0) + N * c2

Comment: @Pavel strange thing is that in Firebird is not linear and 10000 loops needs almost the same time as 10... why is that?

Comment: @Steffen: I don't know, but I for me a Firebird behave is strange - 10 and 10000x execution should not be same. Please, can me send a full test case? I can look a little bit deep. There can be a bug in pg too. 9.4 is fresh release.

Comment: @Steffen: other possibility are a different execution plans of inner query - a size of table, indexes, .. can have big impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it... It was an index problem but it makes not complete sense to me...

Because if I executed the SQLs outside the function they were even faster than Firebird with Indizes. Now they are outside the functions in Postgres even twice as fast as before and the functions works now also really fast. Also faster as in Firebird...

The reason why I also was not considering this is because in Firebird the Foreign Keys also works as indizes. I expected would be the same in Postgres but it's not...

Should have really considered that earlier also because of the comments of Frank and Pavel.

Thanks to all anyways...

Answer (score 1):

PL/pgSQL reuses prepared queries across function invocations; you only incur preparation overhead once per session. So unless you've been reconnecting between each test, the linear execution times are expected.

But it may also reuse execution plans, and sometimes this does not work to your advantage. Running your query in an `EXECUTE` statement can give better performance, despite the overhead of repreparing it each time.

See the [PL/pgSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING) for more detail.